# openss.dll failed to start with ampps web server

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use the openssl.dll extension of the php extension while installing laravel framework. As soon as i check the option and restart AMPPS it gives the following error
"PHP Startuo Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php\ext\php_openssl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1"

Comment: So is that dynamic library in the specified path?

Comment: Anyway, this is not a good place for such question. Check [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).